# Accessing internal server using an iPad connected to a router with no DNS server

Tags: networking, ipad

I have an **iPad(iOS 6)** connected to a router which has a DHCP pool. I want to access sites hosted on the internal servers by using the *system name* instead of the *IP address*. But I have no provision to use a *DNS server*!

**Eg:** Use *http://mySys/PersonalWeb/home.aspx* instead of *http://176.11.x.y/PersonalWeb/home.aspx*

Is it even possible? If yes, how?

**PS:** Please pardon my limited knowledge with network related stuff. I would be happy to provide further details, if any required.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your question, no not without jailbreaking the device and editing the host file (i would not recommend this)

Does your router not run DNS, most home routers do. I assume your other computers connected to your router are able to connect via the dns name?

In that case, you have two options.
1.Jailbreak the device and edit the host file (again not something i can recommend)

2.Install a dns server onto one of your servers.

If its a windows server which im guessing it is as your trying to access aspx pages, then the installation of the DNS service is fairly straight forward, with plenty of resources around on the internet.

Comment: The iPad is connected to a lame router that does not run DNS!

Comment: The router does DHCP? What make and model?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Its DLINK DIR-600L